# find and move text between boundaries

Tags: regex, shell, text, awk, sed

I have a huge text file with a collection of texts in this format:

`<text id="1">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
</text>
<text id="2">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
</text>
<text id="3">`

.....etc. up to 14.400

at some point(s) I have this situation:

`<text id="XXX">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
</text>
**text out of bounds**
<text id="XXX">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah`

I mean, somewhere there are text out of the boundaries of text tags, I need to locate those lines of text and move them inside of the previous block, so the resulting structure is like this:

`<text id="XXX">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
**text moved in bounds**
</text>
<text id="XXX">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah`

In other words, it can not be text beween `</text>` and `<text id="....`

Comment: What did you try so far? What are your constraints?

Comment: nothing yet, I mean i did this, which is not a real solution:

Comment: sorry.. : this: `sed -i -r 's/^(<text id=")/<\/text>\n\1/g' file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't print the `</text` line until you see the next `<text` line or reach the end of the input file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/<\/text/ { end = $0 ORS; next }
/<text/   { printf "%s", end; end="" }
{ print }
END { printf "%s", end }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<text id="XXX">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah
blah
**text out of bounds**
</text>
<text id="XXX">
blah blah blah blah
blah blah
```

That will work in any awk on any OS and the only memory it'll use is just enough to store the longest `</text` line.

Comment: I don't understand the question. My answer shows the code and shows it being executed.

Comment: The part you show with $cat tst.awk is all the code for the script or I have to add this to the code given by @oliv or replace at it. The thing is that I don't see any command at your $ cat tst.awk output (no awk)

Comment: That's all there is. There's a file named `tst.awk` containing the awk script you see being output by `cat tst.awk`. To execute it you do `awk -f tst.awk file` exactly as shown below the `cat` output. `file` is your input file.

Comment: If you don't want to put the script in a file you can execute it as `awk 'script' file` instead of `awk -f tst.awk file` of course (like oliv shows in her answer) and just replace `script` with the contents of `tst.awk` shown in my answer.

Comment: Wow, that was super fast, I `did awk -f boundtext.awk file.in > file.out` I can not belive the fast it did it!!!!! Million thanks....

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, awk is highly optimized for text manipulation and so an awk script will typically run faster than a compiled C program (and orders of magnitude faster than a shell script that doesn't just call awk) for the same task as long as that task is just text manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` script:

```
awk -v RS='<text id="[^"]*">[^<]*</text>' '
    NF==0 && prev{print prev}
    NF>0{
        printf "%s", substr(prev, 1, index(prev, "</text>")-2)
        printf "%s", $0
        print  "</text>"
    }
    {prev=RT}' file
```

The record separator `RS` is matching everything enclosed between `<text id=...>` and `</text>`. So if something is out of these 2 tags, the number of field `NF` will be set.

For each record, the variable is `prev` is set with the record terminator `RT` which contains the current `RS` content.

In case there is nothing between the 2 tags `NF==0`, just print the record terminator the previous `RT` stored in `prev`.

In case something is *out of bounds* (`NF>0`), then print everything before the end tag contained of the previous record. Note the `index(...)-2` to avoid printing the `\n` and `<` characters of the end tag. At last print the end tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error: `awk: line cmd.:2: (FILENAME=file.txt FNR=1) fatal: grow_fields_arr: fields_arr: can't allocate 432226288 bytes of memory`

Comment: Question: is this command operating over the file or do I have to redirect the output?

Comment: @AndrésChandía The `awk` command is displaying the modified file into the terminal you executed the command. You may re-direct the output to another file. To answer your first remark, it looks like `awk` cannot find the first element `FNR=1`. Possibly `RS` variable has to be adapted, but at least this means the file you tested differs from the one you posted.

Comment: Ok, at the RS you have put an extra X: now is `RS='<text id="[0-9]*">[^<]*</text>'`. Some tags are: `<text id="1241">, <text id="2146">, <text id="94">`, etc. but anyway I get the error: `awk: line cmd.:2: (FILENAME=file.txt FNR=1) fatal: grow_fields_arr: fields_arr: can't allocate 428171248 bytes of memory` and I put a `file > file.out` at the end, but file.out is 0 bytes

Comment: The extra `X` is on purpose to cope with the test you posted. Your file appears to be quite big. Try copying part of it, with only 4 or 5 blocks with some text  inbetween (just like your example). If that does work, it is probably linked to the version of  `awk` you're using. FYI your example works fine with my version of `gawk` (which is 4.1.3).

Comment: Mine is gawk -V GNU Awk 4.1.1. File is 353M. And yes, your srcipt works with the exemple, with or without the X. So how can I deal with the memory issue?

Comment: @AndrésChandía - You're asking for help debugging code you haven't shown us. Your error message says that you have a function or something named `grow_fields_arr` within which you have an array named `fields_arr` that is using up too much memory. There are no arrays or functions in any of the awk code posted or discussed so far so what are we supposed to to help you debug that error message?

Comment: @oliv - Never do `printf $0` or similar to print input data, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead. Imagine the difference if `$0` contains printf formatting characters like `%s`. You should state that your solution is gawk-specific due to multi-char RS and RT.

Comment: @EdMorton, No, I have no other code than the one given by oliv

Comment: @AndrésChandía ah, then those messages must be reporting array and function names internal to gawk. That's unfortunate! My guess is that your RS never matches anything so awk is trying to split the whole file into space-separated fields. To debug it, reduce the RS to, say, just `<text` and see what that does (add `NR==1{print "<"$0":"RT">";exit}`). Then keep adding back parts of the original RS until it fails and THAT will tell you what is causing the specified RS to not match anything in your input file.

Comment: FWIW I bet your "id"s do NOT just contain numbers or X as you've shown in your question and oliv has replicated in her answer and instead or additionally contain letters or other characters. Personally I'd use `"[^"]*"` instead of `"[0-9X]*"`.

Comment: note - the above will fail if any of the `blah blah blah` text contains a `<`.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for your comment, i changed the script.